# How to save a query result into a column using postgresql

Tags: postgresql, sorting, multiple-columns

This may be a simple fix but Im somehow drawing a blank.  I have this code below, and I want the results that I got from it to be added into their own column in an existing table.  How would i go about doing this.

```
Select full_name, SUM(total) as sum_sales
FROM loyalty
where invoiceyear = 2013
GROUP BY full_name
order by sum_sales DESC;
```

This leaves me with one column with the name of employee and the second with their sales from that year.

How can i just take these results and add them into a column in addition to the table

Is it as simple as...

```
Alter table loyalty
Add column "2013 sales"
```

and then add in some sort of condition?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why? 1) You have demonstrated you can pull this information out at any time with a query. 2) You are trying to add an aggregated value to individual rows, so there will be duplication of data. You would be better of making a view from the query.

Comment: The `sum(total)` is cause by more than 1 row in the table `loyalty`. You should not store this value in 1 row in the same table.  You might want to store it in a history table since 2013 is now 10 years old.

Comment: I would like to have them displayed in their own column by specific year, instead of just all the years being in one column.  I know the information is readilly available and its more time consuming doing it this way, but I was just seeing if theres a quick way to add columns after you get your results from the query

Comment: Yes it is called [CREATE VIEW](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html).

Answer (score 0):

If i got your question right, you need to first alter the table allowing the new field to be null (you can change it later on) then you could use an insert clause to store the value permanently.